# Objective function vs evaluation metric

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I was reading XGBoost's documentation here: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html.

It's not immediately clear to me how the objective function and evaluation metric differs in their purpose. Which one is minimized in training? Are both used somehow?

Comment: Despite the reference to Keras in the linked questions, the answers are in fact generally applicable, and clarify the differences between the objective function (loss) and the evaluation (or business) metrics, like the accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I believe the answers there explain the point well - thanks for pointing me to them.